# django staticfiles error

Tags: python, django

How come my static files don't serve? or only some of them I can't tell. I have tried just about everything. and I don't know where the problem is. I need support for getting my staticfiles to work during development and production. but help me with development first please

I am trying to get my staticfiles to work, and i get this error

```
Django version 1.4.3, using settings 'menu.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[10/Mar/2013 15:12:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1868
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    start_response)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 57, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 50, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/views.py", line 36, in serve
    absolute_path = finders.find(normalized_path)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/finders.py", line 238, in find
    for finder in get_finders():
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/finders.py", line 256, in get_finders
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 27, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/finders.py", line 277, in _get_finder
    (Finder, BaseFinder))
ImproperlyConfigured: Finder "<class 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder'>" is not a subclass of "<class 'staticfiles.finders.BaseFinder'>"
[10/Mar/2013 15:12:37] "GET /static/css/screen.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    start_response)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 57, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 50, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/views.py", line 36, in serve
    absolute_path = finders.find(normalized_path)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/finders.py", line 238, in find
    for finder in get_finders():
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/finders.py", line 256, in get_finders
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 27, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/talisman/virt_env/menu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/staticfiles/finders.py", line 277, in _get_finder
    (Finder, BaseFinder))
ImproperlyConfigured: Finder "<class 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder'>" is not a subclass of "<class 'staticfiles.finders.BaseFinder'>"
[10/Mar/2013 15:12:37] "GET /static/css/print.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

this is my settings.py

```
if socket.gethostname() == 'Pangolin': #Brian's Development Laptop
    DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/home/talisman/projects/menu/templates',)
    SQL_LITE_NAME = '/home/talisman/projects/menu/db4.db'
    STATIC_ROOT = '/home/talisman/projects/menu/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
        '/home/talisman/projects/menu/staticfiles/',
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misconfigured staticfiles in your settings maybe?

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

make sure you have the context processor:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    ...
]
```

Also don't use paths like that, used to provide absolute paths...

```
from os.path import join, dirname, normpath

LOCAL_PATH = normpath(join(dirname(__file__), '..'))
```

then you can do...

```
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    LOCAL_PATH + '/public/common/',
)
```

=========

here is an example of how I set mine up

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = '/uploaded/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    LOCAL_PATH + '/public/common/',
)

    # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

In my installed apps I make sure I have

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

Comment: nope, i have that correct STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

Comment: but you are right, I comment one out it just errors down the list How do I fix it?

Comment: my media root is MEDIA_URL = ''''  what should it be?

Comment: in your INSTALLED_APPS do you have 'django.contrib.staticfiles'?

Comment: I have django.contrib.staticfiles in my INSTALLED_APP